# XAMPP, Apache and IIS on the same machine

Tags: apache, iis, xampp

Im trying to run XAMPP on the same machine as IIS but I cant make apache work. I changed the ports to 8080 and 4333 but I still cant run it. If I stop IIS service, apache starts normally. Is there any way to make it work here?

thanks.

Comment: you need to check either you are using skype or some other application which blocks the port access, which you can change by options in skype

Comment: Check your apache http servers error log file to find out the exact issue at hand.

Comment: i dont have skype. nothing in logs. It just does not start. Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

These should work together as long as not colliding on ports, I currently run both at same time myself, and have run into same pain you have.  XAMPP Apache doesn't say which port, it just don't start.

I commented out all "443 Listen" & "NameVirtualHost *:443" entries - (with #) , and changed xampp sites to a non iis port (my case 86) in apache\conf\httpd.conf, but also be sure you check the config(s) in E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra.  xampp has "extra" configs there.

Be sure to check that D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf is not set to use\listen on 443.

updating answer here a bit...

Actually you may just need to comment the Listen 443 line, (change to #Listen 443, or change to 4333 or what ever) in D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf at about line 36 or so. The section in that file with ..

```
    <VirtualHost  default:443>
```

defined can just sit there unused if you dont need it then, so no need to comment that section out for now.

Sorry, that was actually my issue - I did this so long ago I forgot.   Apache files are not set up the same way.

...

Basically there is a port conflict you need to clear up. also be sure you dont leave "copied" or "backed" up conf files with the .conf extension in the conf folders - sometimes those get grabbed and used.  Good luck on your dup port Hunt.

... putting my comments here because they may be getting buried...

ok, just try commenting out any listen settings other than the one you need (8081) in the config files instead (httpd.conf, extra/httpd-ssl.conf & extra/httpd-vhosts.conf). You may be bumping into your own listen settings elsewhere in your conf files. one time i mistakenly set 443 in main httpd.conf and in ssl.conf. besides you might not need 443 at all anyway. the answer is in your conf files somewhere. perhaps a file contents search for "listen" in the /conf/ folder might help.

also you may want to check out the "netstat" button from xampp panel - it should tell you a bit more about what is using what ports, that sometimes gives good clues

And if you did not know or are new to xampp/apache VERY IMPORTANT

REMEMBER TO RESTART APACHE AFTER ANY CONF CHANGE !

Comment: I have changed SSL to 442 but its still using 443, where else i could have it? https://snag.gy/HFkLgU.jpg

Comment: D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf  has 443 settings - comment  those out.   which conf files have you updated so far?

Comment: Actually I think you just need to comment the Listen 443 line, (change to #Listen 443, or change to 4333 or what ever) in D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf at about line 39. The section with <VirtualHost  default:443 defined> can just sit there unused then, so no need to comment that section out for now.

Comment: hey. I changed to \apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf  Listen 4433 and also change the port in the Control panel, but its still the same. if IIS is of it uses 8081 but still 433.. https://snag.gy/LS1C57.jpg

Comment: ok, just try commenting out any listen settings other than the one you need (8081) in the config files instead (httpd.conf, extra/httpd-ssl.conf &  extra/httpd-vhosts.conf).   You may be bumping into your own listen settings elsewhere in your conf files.  one time i mistakenly set 443 in main httpd.conf and in ssl.conf. besides you might not need 443 at all anyway.  the answer is in your conf files somewhere.  perhaps a file contents search for "listen" in the /conf/ folder might help.

Comment: also you may want to check out the "netstat" button from xampp panel - it should tell you a bit more about what is using what ports, that sometimes gives good clues.